# exclude imports in typescript (context of lambda layer)

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-lambda-layers

I’m working with aws amplify, and uses lambda layers and also typescript.
Because my project is big, I simplified my folder structure to explain my problem

[image: Folderstructure]

On the root level i have the amplify folder, which contains an inside a folder for each lambda function and each lambda layers.

Also on the root level, I introduced an "amplifyTypescript" folder, which contains also folders for each lambda and each lamda layer for the typescript sources.

The tsconfig.json looks like this.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "../../amplify/backend/function/lambdaFunction1",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
        "/opt/lambdaLayer/database/index": ["../lambdaLayer/database/index"]
    }
},
"exclude": [
    "../lambdaLayer/",
    "lambdaLayer/database/index.ts",
    "**/lambdaLayer**",
    "../lambdaLayer/database/index",
    "/opt/lambdaLayer/database/index"
]
```

}

In lambdaFunction1 i have the following import statement.
import { fConnect } from '/opt/lambdaLayer/database/index';

The Problem which occurred at first was, that the path /opt/... obviosly didn't exist on my laptop.
Therefore i introduced the mapping of paths in the tsconfig (see above).

Then i got the error that ../lambdaLayer/database/index is outside of the "rootDir" of lambdaFunction1.
This is correct, but it's a lambdaLayer. At the End I want to ignore this at transpile process....

Therefore i ignored this error using: // @ts-ignore

Now everything works fine during development. The IDE considers the path-mapping in tsconfig, and i can develop my code.
But when i run "tsc" in lambdaFunction1, the system tries to transpile the lambdaLayer also, and this throws several issues regarding problems with relatives paths.

As you can see, i tried it with several excludes in tsconfig, but as far as i learned, excludes are ignored if there is an import statement.

Currently i haven't a clue, how to handle this situation. Typescript should just "believe" me, that at the end the file will be accessable via: /opt/lambdaLayer/database/index

Can someone help me?

Kind Regards
Stefan

Comment: Really good question. Unfortunately no answer :/